# Prove$\frac{d}{dx}g(x,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove if $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, then:

$\frac{d}{dx}g(x,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,x)$

My work:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,x)=g'(x,x)g(1,1)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,x)=0$

I try to calculate the partial derivatives of the $g$ function but after that step i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short notation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}g(h(x),r(x))=g_xh_x+g_yr_x=g_x+g_y$$

since:

$$h_x=r_x=(x)'=1$$

Comment: A bit too short.

Comment: @egreg I've udated in a less short notation!

Comment: Thanks, is better that notation.

Comment: You're welcome, I like so much short notation!

Comment: Your last equation: $h_x=r_x=(x)'=1$ is because $h_x=r_x=x$ and $h_x'=r_x'=(x)'=1$ then we obtain the result, no?

Comment: yes exactly, It should be indicated as $\frac{\partial x}{ \partial x}=1$

Comment: Note that: h=r=x

Answer (score 1):

By chain rule: $$\frac{d}{dx}g(x, y)=g_x(x,y)\frac{dx}{dx}+g_y(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}=g_x(x,y)+g_y(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}$$ if $y=y(x)$. Then if we put $y=x$, we get the desired equality.

Comment: I don't see very clear the chain rule... $\frac{d}{dx}g(x, y)=g_x(x,y)\frac{dx}{dx}+g_y(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}$ This step is not very clear for me. Can explain me that step?

Comment: let $x=f(t)$ and $y=h(t)$. Then by the chain rule:  $$\frac{d}{dt}g\big(f(t), h(t)\big)=g_x\big(f(t), h(t)\big)\frac{df}{dt}+g_y(f(t), h(t))\frac{dh}{dt}=g_xf(t), h(t))f'(t)+g_y(f(t), h(t))h'(t).$$ In your case you take $x=t$ and $y=t$.  (Here $t$ is the independent variable) (ypu can replace $t$ and $x$ to have your cequality.